# Android ListAdapter NullPointerException using Volley

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I'm running into a perpetual issue with getting an NPE when my ListAdapter calls getCount() after initialization. I populate my array of "Sound" items using Volley, but the app still crashes on start.

I've been using this tutorial for help: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/. The tricky thing about my app is that I have to do everything within fragments, since I have a tabbed interface and the feed I'm trying to build is hosted within a tab.

Below is my code:

Relevant code from LandingActivity.java:

```
Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                           .setIcon(R.drawable.feed_icon)
                           .setTabListener(new TabListener<SoundFragment>(this, "feed", SoundFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

My SoundFragment.java file:

```
public class SoundFragment extends ListFragment {
    private static final String TAG = "SoundFragment";
    private ArrayList<Sound> mSounds;
    private AudioRecorder mPlayer = new AudioRecorder();
    private ImageButton mImageButton;
    SoundAdapter adapter;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://puncture.org/wavesdemo/feed.json";

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sound, parent, false);
            return v;
        }

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            // First check for cached request
            Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
            Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
            if (entry != null) {
                // Fetch the data from cache
                try {
                    String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                    try {
                        parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                        Log.w("DEBUG", "JSON feed parsed from cache!");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    Log.w("DEBUG", "UnsupportedEncodingException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                // making fresh volley request and getting JSON
                Log.w("DEBUG", "onResponse method hit within JsonObjectRequest");
                JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                        URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.w("DEBUG", "onResponse method hit within JsonObjectRequest");
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                        if (response != null) {
                        parseJsonFeed(response);
                        }
                        }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.w("DEBUG", "onErrorResponse method hit within JsonObjectRequest");
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                        });



                // Adding request to volley request queue
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
                Log.w("DEBUG", "AppController getInstance request queue thing hit.");

            }
            Log.w("DEBUG", "Made it to the end!!");
            adapter = new SoundAdapter(getActivity(), com.littlecloudcollective.waves.R.layout.fragment_sound_item, mSounds);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            Log.w("DEBUG", "ListAdapter set!");

        }

    /**      * Parsing JSON response and passing the data to feed view list adapter      * */
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                Sound s = new Sound();
                s.setId(feedObj.getInt("sound_id"));
                s.setSound(feedObj.getString("sound"));
                Log.w("DEBUG", feedObj.getString("sound"));
                s.setSoundViz(feedObj.getString("sound_viz"));
                Log.w("DEBUG", feedObj.getString("sound_viz"));
                s.setLocation(feedObj.getString("location"));
                // Title might be null sometimes
                String feedTime = feedObj.isNull("title") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("title");
                s.setTitle(feedTime);
                s.setTime(feedObj.getString("time"));
                s.setLatitude(feedObj.getDouble("latitude"));
                s.setLongitude(feedObj.getDouble("longitude"));
                s.setUserId(feedObj.getString("user_id"));
                s.setUsername(feedObj.getString("username"));
                //Profile photo might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("profile_photo") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("profile_photo");
                s.setProfilePhoto(image);

                mSounds.add(s);             }

            // Notify data changes to list adapter          
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And my SoundAdapter.java class:

```
public class SoundAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sound> {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Sound> feedItems;
    private Date now = new Date();
    private long now1 = now.getTime();
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public SoundAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Sound> feedItems) {
        super(context, resource, feedItems);
        Log.w("DEBUG", "It made it to the SoundAdapter creation!");
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
    }

    @Override
        public int getCount() {
            Log.w("DEBUG", "Now it's trying to getCount! Cue the crash.");
            return feedItems.size();
        } 

    @Override
        public Sound getItem(int location) {
            return feedItems.get(location);
        }

    @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sound_item, null);

            if (imageLoader == null)
                imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

            Sound s = getItem(position);

            TextView titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sound_title);
            titleTextView.setText(s.getTitle().toString());
            TextView usernameTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.username_label);
            usernameTextView.setText(s.getUsername().toString());
            TextView locationTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sound_location);
            locationTextView.setText(s.getLocation().toString());


            String timestamp = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(Long.parseLong(s.getTime()), System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
            TextView timeTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.time_label);
            timeTextView.setText(timestamp);

            FeedImageView mSoundVizView = (FeedImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sound_vis);

            ImageView mapImageView = new ImageView(activity);
            Picasso.with(activity)
                .load("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Rio+de+Janeiro,Brazil&zoom=11&size=250x150")
                .into(mapImageView);

            NetworkImageView profilePhotoView = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_photo);

            // Chcek for empty status message
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.getTitle())) {
                titleTextView.setText(s.getTitle());
                titleTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                // status is empty, remove from view
                titleTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


            // user profile pic
            profilePhotoView.setImageUrl(s.getProfilePhoto(), imageLoader);

            // Feed image
            if (s.getSoundViz() != null) {
                mSoundVizView.setImageUrl(s.getSoundViz(), imageLoader);
                mSoundVizView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mSoundVizView
                    .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                            }
                            });
            } else {
                mSoundVizView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


            return convertView;
        }


}
```

And then here are my XML files:

In fragment_sound_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pin_map_icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sound_location"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pin_map_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sound_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sound_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/sound_location_label"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sound_location"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sound_location"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/sound_time_label"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <com.littlecloudcollective.waves.FeedImageView
            android:id="@+id/sound_map"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sound_vis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/sound_vis_2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="@string/user_username_label"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sound_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/sound_title_label"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username_label"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username_label"
        android:src="@drawable/divider" />

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/time_label"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container"
        android:src="@drawable/default_profile_thumbnail" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And fragment_sound.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@android:id/list" />
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
02-19 14:02:11.229: W/DEBUG(20532): onResponse method hit within JsonObjectRequest
02-19 14:02:11.239: W/DEBUG(20532): AppController getInstance request queue thing hit.
02-19 14:02:11.239: W/DEBUG(20532): Made it to the end!!
02-19 14:02:11.239: W/DEBUG(20532): It made it to the SoundAdapter creation!
02-19 14:02:11.239: W/DEBUG(20532): ListAdapter set!
02-19 14:02:11.289: D/AbsListView(20532): Get MotionRecognitionManager
02-19 14:02:11.319: W/DEBUG(20532): Now it's trying to getCount! Cue the crash.
02-19 14:02:11.319: D/AndroidRuntime(20532): Shutting down VM
02-19 14:02:11.319: W/dalvikvm(20532): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41764438)
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.littlecloudcollective.waves/com.littlecloudcollective.waves.LandingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532):    at com.littlecloudcollective.waves.SoundAdapter.getCount(SoundAdapter.java:42)
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:466)
02-19 14:02:11.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20532):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListAdapter(ListFragment.java:182)
```

Secondary error, after making activity to context changes and updating this.feedItems bit in SoundAdapter:

```
02-19 14:46:21.479: E/AndroidRuntime(21538): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 14:46:21.479: E/AndroidRuntime(21538):    at com.littlecloudcollective.waves.SoundAdapter.<init>(SoundAdapter.java:36)
02-19 14:46:21.479: E/AndroidRuntime(21538):    at com.littlecloudcollective.waves.SoundFragment.onCreate(SoundFragment.java:97)
02-19 14:46:21.479: E/AndroidRuntime(21538):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
```

This is my first Android app, so I suspect I've mixed up something somewhere about Fragments. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is line 42 in `soundAdapter.java`?

Comment: I am not sure ,but you are writing this.activity = activity, but your adapter parameters doesn't contain activity. You have to do write this.context = context;

Comment: Hi Josef and Surender, thanks for your comments. Line 42 above is what used to be this.feedItems = feedItems, though I changed it according to TheRedFox's suggestion below (as well as the activity to context change, thanks for that) however it's still giving me an error. Edited included above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always avoid doing

```
this.feedItems = feedItems;
```

it is much better to do like this:

```
//Initialize your List
private ArrayList<Sound> feedItems = new ArrayList<Sound>();

public SoundAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Sound> feedItems) {
    super(context, resource, feedItems);
    this.feedItems.clear();
    this.feedItems.addAll(feedItems);
}
```

In this way `feedItems` will never point to a `null` object.

Comment: Hi @TheRedFox, very good to know, thanks. I changed that in the code (as well as the above suggested activity-to-context change) and I still get an NPE pointing to line 36 of SoundAdapter, which is actually the this.feedItems.clear() line.

Comment: Hmm...redid the initialization in a few ways, including yours, and am still getting the same NPE error (the secondary one included as an edit in my original post)!

Comment: If you are doing everything right there is no way to get a NPE i editeed the code to make it clear

Comment: Okay, I took out all initializations and then just put some back in and it worked now! You are correct, no more NPE...though now I'm just getting a blank screen, but that's a separate issue :) Thank you, @TheRedFox!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize the `mSounds` list. Add this line to your `onCreate` method before setting the adapter. Also make sur your adapter is not null when you call `parseJsonFeed`. Perhaps that's the NPE you are getting. Just to make sure you should create you adapter before anything else:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    // First check for cached request
    Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);

    mSounds = new ArrayList<Sound>();       //<-- Add this line so your list is not null

    //And initialize your adapter from the beggining
    adapter = new SoundAdapter(getActivity(), com.littlecloudcollective.waves.R.layout.fragment_sound_item, mSounds);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    Log.w("DEBUG", "ListAdapter set!");

    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Carlos, mSounds does get initialized up at the top of SoundAdapter, private ArrayList<Sound> mSounds. However, I still tried your suggestion and it sadly didn't change anything :-/

Comment: I don't see any initialization of the list on your array. Also I just realized you add items to the list before setting the adapter so you need to initialize the list before that. I edited my question. Basically just move the initialization up.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps